# Definir valor min y maximo de input recien creado en javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Creo un input de la siguiente forma:

```
var monto_inp = document.createElement("input");
monto_inp.name = "monto";
monto_inp.placeholder = "Monto";
monto_inp.classList.add('detalle_pago');
monto_inp.classList.add('monto');
```

Me gustaría agregarle un valor mínimo y máximo con min y max, intente con monto_inp.min pero no funciono.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En **javascript**, para modificar los atributos de un elemento html o añadir-los debes usar la función `setAttribute(name, value);`:

> Establece el valor de un atributo en el elemento indicado. Si el
>   atributo ya existe, el valor es actualizado, en caso contrario, el
>   nuevo atributo es añadido con el nombre y valor indicado.

**Sintaxis**

```
Element.setAttribute(name, value);
```

**`name`**

> Un DOMString indicando el nombre del atributo cuyo valor se va a
>   cambiar. El nombre del atributo se convierte automáticamente en
>   minúsculas cuando setAttribute() se llama sobre un elemento HTML en un
>   documento HTML.

**`value`**

> Un DOMString que contenga el valor que asignar al atributo. Cualquier
>   valor indicado que no sea una cadena de texto se convierte
>   automáticamente en una cadena de texto.

[Documentación.](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Teniendo en cuenta la documentación prueba con esto:

```
    var monto_inp = document.createElement("input");
    monto_inp.setAttribute("type","number");
    monto_inp.setAttribute("max",100);
    monto_inp.setAttribute("min",2);
```

Comment: Hola Lucas, las respuestas que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad. Por favor, añade algo más de detalle: ¿qué cambios sugieres? ¿por qué resolverían el problema? Lee [answer] para más información.