# ¿cómo hacer que los atributos max y min de un input cambien al seleccionar una opción de un select?

Tags: javascript, html, options

Quisiera saber como hacer para manipular el max y min de un input desde javascript, soy nuevo en esto y tengo muchas dudas aun...el punto es mediante un select al momento de elegir una opción los atributos del max y min cambien..

```js
const loanForm = document.getElementById('calculate-loan-form')
loanForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  start_loader();

  const interest = document.getElementById('loan-interest').value;
  const principalAmount = document.getElementById('loan-amount').value;
  const PayableYears = document.getElementById('loan-years').value;
  
  /////////////////////////////////////////// ATRIBUTOS DE MONTO/////////////////////////////////
  var iva = .16,
    input = document.getElementById("loan-amount");

  if (interest == 27) {//ORDINARIO
    input.setAttribute("max", 5000000);
    input.setAttribute("min", 600);
  } else if (interest == 18) {//CREDICONFIANZA
    input.setAttribute("max", 150000);
    input.setAttribute("min", 600);
  } else if (interest == 22.80) {//TEMPORADA
    input.setAttribute("max", 40000);
    input.setAttribute("min", 600);
  } else if (interest == 13.80) {//TU AUTO
    input.setAttribute("max", 700000);
    input.setAttribute("min", 25000);
  } else if (interest == 11.40) {//TU CASA
    input.setAttribute("max", 2000000);
    input.setAttribute("min", 100000);
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="loan-interest"><b>SELECCIONE EL TIPO DE CRÉDITO</b></label>
  <select class="form-select" name="loan-interest" id="loan-interest"
          placeholder="INGRESE EL MONTO DESEADO" class="input-item text-right"
          required>
    <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
    <option value="27">ORDINARIO</option>
    <option value="18">CREDICONFIANZA</option>
    <option value="22.80">TEMPORADA</option>
    <option value="13.80">TU AUTO</option>
    <option value="11.40">TU CASA</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="loan-amount"><b>MONTO</b></label>
  <input type="number" step="1" value="600" min='input' max="input" name="loan-amount"
         id="loan-amount"
         class="form-control" required>
</div>
```

Lo que quiero lograr es que los atributos max y min del input "MONTO"se actualicen al seleccionar una opción del select

al hacerlo así una vez enviado el formulario no me valida el input sino hasta la segunda vez que lo envió

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Definir valor min y maximo de input recien creado en javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/193247/definir-valor-min-y-maximo-de-input-recien-creado-en-javascript)

Comment: no amigo busco otra solución, ya modifique la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se debe a que estas modificando el `min` y `max` del `<input` **después de evento `submit`** del formulario.

### Solución:

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- (*Opcional*) Crear un objeto con la configuración de los limites `min` y `max` según el tipo de crédito seleccionado.
- Suscribir una función al evento [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) del `<select`.
  Cuando el usuario modifique la selección entonces ahí establecemos el `min` y `max` en base a la opción seleccionada.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
const interest = document.getElementById('loan-interest');
const amount = document.getElementById("loan-amount");
const loanForm = document.getElementById('calculate-loan-form');
const interestMinMax = {
  '27': {min: 600, max: 5000000}, // ORDINARIO
  '18': {min: 600, max: 150000}, // CREDICONFIANZA
  '22.80': {min: 600, max: 40000}, // TEMPORADA
  '13.80': {min: 25000, max: 700000}, // TU AUTO
  '11.40': {min: 100000, max: 2000000},// TU CASA
  'default': {min: 0, max: 0}
};

interest.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const config = interestMinMax[interest.value] || interestMinMax.default;

  amount.min = config.min;
  amount.max = config.max;
});

loanForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // resto del código...
});
```

```html
<form id="calculate-loan-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="loan-interest"><b>SELECCIONE EL TIPO DE CRÉDITO</b></label>
    <select class="form-select" name="loan-interest" id="loan-interest" placeholder="INGRESE EL MONTO DESEADO" class="input-item text-right" required>
      <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
      <option value="27">ORDINARIO</option>
      <option value="18">CREDICONFIANZA</option>
      <option value="22.80">TEMPORADA</option>
      <option value="13.80">TU AUTO</option>
      <option value="11.40">TU CASA</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="loan-amount"><b>MONTO</b></label>
    <input type="number" step="1" value="1" min='0' max="0" name="loan-amount" id="loan-amount" class="form-control" required>
  </div>
  <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias por el apoyo ya realice tal cual me has asesorado y me funciono, muchas gracias.